# Using InstaLoader in Python module

Tags: python, instagram

I am trying to download photos related to a hashtag for image analysis using Instaloader. I found a comprehensive way in GitHub repository, how to execute it in Terminal. However, I need to integrate the script in Python notebook.

Here is the script: `$ instaloader --no-videos --no-metadata-json --no-captions "#streetart"`

I tried this:

```py
import instaloader
loader = instaloader.Instaloader()
loader.download_hashtag('amg', max_count=20)
```

But I could not find a way to filter the results to return pictures only as output. Can anybody help me please?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import instaloader

loader = instaloader.Instaloader(download_videos=False, save_metadata=False, post_metadata_txt_pattern='')
loader.download_hashtag('streetart', max_count=20)
```