# Anybody know how to only get pictures and not videos using the instaloader package on python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to scrape only pictures from instagram. I am currently getting both pictures and videos while using the instaloader. Does anyone know if there is some parameter that I can use so that I only get pictures returned?

```
L = instaloader.Instaloader( 
        download_pictures=True,
        download_videos=False, 
        download_video_thumbnails=False,
        compress_json=False, 
        download_geotags=False, 
        post_metadata_txt_pattern=None, 
        max_connection_attempts=0,
        download_comments=False,
        )
    profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, username)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60074347/12128167 I've no clue. You may check out these parameters. But seems like you already have them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already tried to read the "help" documentation from instaloader?

try type `instaloader --help`, and you will see the command option for excluding video using instaloader, which is `--no-videos`

example:

`$ instaloader arianagrande --no-videos`

this will scrape post from arianagrande profile, but excluding post that has video.

Answer (score 0):

to download images only do change username with the account name :

```
instaloader username --no-videos --no-captions --no-metadata-json --no-compress-json --no-resume --no-iphone
```